# Multiply Checkbox Value with Input Box Value - Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently struggling to get the value I return from a checkbox to multiply with the value in the input box with jQuery.

I display a div when a checkbox is ticked to ask it for the quantity, thereafter I must multiply the quantity with the value of the checkbox.

Here is the current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var qty = 0;

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        recalculateQty();
        recalculateCheck();
        if ($('#1').is(':checked')) {
            $('#checked-1').show();
        } else {
            $('#checked-1').hide();
        }
        if ($('#2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#checked-2').show();
        } else {
            $('#checked-2').hide();
        }
        if ($('#3').is(':checked')) {
            $('#checked-3').show();
        } else {
            $('#checked-3').hide();
        }
    });

    function recalculateQty() {
        $('.qty').keyup(function () {
            $('.qty').each(function () {
                qty += parseInt(this.value, 10);
                recalculateCheck();
            });
        });
    }

    function recalculateCheck() {
        var sum = 0;
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('.qty').keyup(function () {
            $('.qty').each(function () {
                qty += parseInt(this.value, 10);
            });
        });
        $('#total').val(sum * qty);
    }
});

<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="30" name="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="60" name="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="90" name="3" />

<div style="display:none;" id="checked-1">
    <input type="text" name="product_1_qty" id="product_1_qty" placeholder="Quantity" class=" qty" value="0" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9vRtJ/1/

Comment: What are you having issues with? Are there errors? Also, what is `recalculateCheck();`, it seems to be missing from the code above.

Comment: You should not mix your JavaScript and PHP code. Do not iterate using PHP here. You should add `var num_products = <?= $num_products ?>;` and iterate using JS: `var x; for(x = 1; x <= num_products; x++) { ... }`.

Comment: Great thanks for the advice, @tymeJV I updated the code with the missing function thanks.

Comment: So what happens when you try this code? Errors or anything? It's a lot to look through without a specific problem point. Also, consider what @Riateche said, mixing JS and PHP can be a real headache to look at.

Comment: Cool thanks, i tried to simplify it a bit and added HTML. There is no errors, accept when it multiplies and the check box is unticked and reticked it remultiplies

Comment: Question updated to clean up code and add fiddle. Where are you expecting the calculated value to be output? There's no #total in your code.

Comment: You're adding two keyup handlers everytime the value changes, you should either just use the change event, or just the keyup event

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mffox/65VSF/1/) ?

Comment: id="1" is not valid, it should start with a non numeric character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set an element value with `total` ID as a final result, but there is no such element in your html code.
 Just add this element in your html code (here i put another textbox):

```
<input type="text" id='total'>
```

Check out the [**Live demo for your fix**](http://jsfiddle.net/9vRtJ/3/)

 Or you can use better coding:(Read the comments) - **[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/9vRtJ/6/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var qty = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        if ($('#1').is(':checked')) {
            $('#checked-1').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#checked-1').hide();
        }
    });
     $('.qty').keyup(function () { // if user typed anyting in the Quantity
          sum = parseInt($('#1').val()); // get checkbox value and change the data type to int
          qty = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Quantity value and change the data type to int
          //console.log(sum,qty);
          if(sum && qty) { // if the values was not empty
              $('#total').val(sum * qty); // show the result in the total element
          } else { // if the values was empty
              $('#total').val(''); // clear the result textbox
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: @CarrieKendall What's the problem? it's working for me. It multiplies the quantity with the value of the checkbox. and puts it inside the second textbox.

Comment: qty is NaN. log the values to see

Comment: @CarrieKendall I do not get this log. I clearly get the result.

Comment: @CarrieKendall [**Watch This**](http://www.mediafire.com/watch/7yh6ioau0run0xd/working.mp4)

Comment: backspace so the input box is empty

Comment: Yup, sorry i forgot to include the total input box, I have that, but it is basically replicating my issue. If you type in a qty in the input box once the checkbox is ticked, it multiplies the value and updates total. Yet when you untick the checkbox and retick it it doubles the value.

Comment: @user2429578 You are doing this in complex way. Is that all your html code? I mean do you have only one `checkbox` and one `Quantity` and one 'total' element in your page?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M i have a number of these check boxes which are products on a page, once ticked it should ask qty, and then multiply those values to give you the total, also when unticked it should removed that amount. Thanks for the input so far, It already is working a lot better. In terms of doing it too complex, just for educational purposes how would it have been done in an easier way ?

Comment: @user2429578 Would you please update your jsFiddle html. that I can see the functionality of? (add 2 or more checkboxes)